# How to put data from a specific column into an one unique row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named dbo.build_main_process with data such as a transaction table with three or can be four different date for the same record. Sometimes the date retun null.

| Product | ProductCode | OperatorName | Step | StepDate | BuildLocatoin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 0_Start | 2019-05-02 | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 1_Material | 2019-05-03 | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 3_Build | 2019-05-06 | ZA |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 0_Start | 2019-05-03 | MX |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 1_Material | 2019-05-06 | MX |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 3_Build | 2019-05-07 | MX |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 0_Start | 2019-05-03 | AR |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 1_Material | null | AR |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 3_Build | 2019-05-06 | AR |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 0_Start | 2019-05-07 | ZA |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 1_Material | 2019-05-08 | ZA |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 3_Build | null | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 0_Start | null | MX |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 1_Material | 2019-05-07 | MX |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | 3_Build | 2019-05-09 | MX |

I need to select data kind a "Excel pivot" for date in columns with unique rows per record:

| Product | ProductCode | OperatorName | 0_Start_Date | 1_Material_Date | 3_Build_Date | BuildLocatoin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2019-05-02 | 2019-05-03 | 2019-05-06 | ZA |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 2019-05-03 | 2019-05-06 | 2019-05-07 | MX |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 2019-05-03 | null | 2019-05-06 | AR |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2019-05-07 | 2019-05-08 | null | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | null | 2019-05-07 | 2019-05-09 | MX |

I'm trying to use "join" in the same table to get unique records with date in columns:

```
select
    t1.Product
    ,t1.ProductCode
    ,t1.OperatorName
    ,case when t1.Step = '0_Start' then StepDate end as 0_Start_Date
    ,case when t2.Step = '1_Material' then StepDate end as 1_Material_Date  
    ,case when t3.Step = '3_Build' then StepDate end as 3_Build_Date
    ,BuildLocatoin  
from 
    dbo.build_main_process as t1
    inner join dbo.build_main_process as t2
        on t1.ProductCode = t2.ProductCode 
        and t1.OperatorName = t2.OperatorName
    inner join dbo.build_main_process as t3
        on t1.ProductCode = t3.ProductCode 
        and t1.OperatorName = t3.OperatorName
go
```

I'm not sure why the result not show unique rows, my result is very similar to this:

| Product | ProductCode | OperatorName | 0_Start_Date | 1_Material_Date | 3_Build_Date | BuildLocatoin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | null | null | null | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2019-05-02 | 2019-05-03 | null | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2019-05-02 | 2019-05-03 | 2019-05-06 | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2019-05-02 | 2019-05-03 | null | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | null | 2019-05-03 | null | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | null | 2019-05-03 | null | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Smith | null | 2019-05-03 | null | ZA |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | null | null | null | MX |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 2019-05-03 | null | null | MX |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 2019-05-03 | 2019-05-06 | 2019-05-07 | MX |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 2019-05-03 | 2019-05-06 | 2019-05-07 | MX |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | 2019-05-03 | null | 2019-05-07 | MX |
| Table | Table_2350 | John Doe | null | null | null | MX |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | null | null | null | AR |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 2019-05-03 | null | null | AR |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 2019-05-03 | null | 2019-05-06 | AR |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 2019-05-03 | null | 2019-05-06 | AR |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | 2019-05-03 | null | 2019-05-06 | AR |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | null | null | null | AR |
| Chair | Black_Chair | Joseph Doe | null | null | null | AR |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | null | null | null | ZA |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | null | null | null | ZA |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | null | null | null | ZA |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2019-05-07 | null | null | ZA |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2019-05-07 | 2019-05-08 | null | ZA |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | 2019-05-07 | 2019-05-08 | null | ZA |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | null | null | null | ZA |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | null | 2019-05-08 | null | ZA |
| Chair | Yellow_Chair | Joseph Smith | null | null | null | ZA |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | null | 2019-05-07 | 2019-05-09 | MX |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | null | 2019-05-07 | null | MX |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | null | 2019-05-07 | 2019-05-09 | MX |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | null | 2019-05-07 | 2019-05-09 | MX |
| Chair | Black_Chair | John Doe | null | 2019-05-07 | null | MX |

Below the DDL:

---Create table

```
create table [dbo].[build_process](
    [Product] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [ProductCode] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [OperatorName] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Step] varchar(15) NULL,
    [StepDate] date NULL,
    [StepTimeinDays] int NULL,
    [BuildLocation] varchar(2) NULL
) on [primary]
go
```

---Populate table

```
insert into [dbo].[build_main_process] values
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Smith','0_Start','2019-05-02','ZA'),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Smith','1_Material','2019-05-03','ZA'),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Smith','3_Build','2019-05-06','ZA'),
    ('Table','Table_2350','John Doe','0_Start','2019-05-03','MX'),
    ('Table','Table_2350','John Doe','1_Material','2019-05-06','MX'),
    ('Table','Table_2350','John Doe','3_Build','2019-05-07','MX'),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Doe','0_Start','2019-05-03','AR'),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Doe','1_Material',null,'AR'),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','Joseph Doe','3_Build','2019-05-06','AR'),
    ('Chair','Yellow_Chair','Joseph Smith','0_Start','2019-05-07','ZA'),
    ('Chair','Yellow_Chair','Joseph Smith','1_Material','2019-05-08','ZA'),
    ('Chair','Yellow_Chair','Joseph Smith','3_Build',null,'ZA'),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','John Doe','0_Start',null,'MX'),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','John Doe','1_Material','2019-05-07','MX'),
    ('Chair','Black_Chair','John Doe','3_Build','2019-05-09','MX')
go
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15). I believe the below query does what you require.

```
-- implicit grouping
SELECT piv.Product, piv.ProductCode, piv.OperatorName, piv.BuildLocation, piv.[0_Start], piv.[1_Material], piv.[3_Build]
FROM #build_process BP
PIVOT (
  MAX(StepDate)
  FOR Step IN ([0_Start], [1_Material], [3_Build])
  ) piv
```

It's worth noting that there is an implicit grouping in a pivot by all non-pivoted columns. In this case, we group by StepTimeInDays but do not show it. For your data schema, assuming valid data, this doesn't seem significant. However, we can make the grouping explicit as below. This is sometimes considered a best practice when working with pivots to make it more obvious how your data ends up grouped.

```
-- explicit grouping
SELECT piv.Product, piv.ProductCode, piv.OperatorName, piv.BuildLocation, piv.[0_Start], piv.[1_Material], piv.[3_Build]
FROM (
  SELECT BP.Product, BP.ProductCode, BP.OperatorName, BP.BuildLocation, BP.Step, MAX(BP.StepDate) StepDate
  FROM #build_process BP
  GROUP BY BP.Product, BP.ProductCode, BP.OperatorName, BP.BuildLocation, BP.Step
  ) grouped
PIVOT (
  MAX(StepDate)
  FOR Step IN ([0_Start], [1_Material], [3_Build])
  ) piv
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed your query a bit and got the result below

```
 SELECT t1.product,
       t1.productcode,
       t1.operatorname,
       CASE
         WHEN t1.step = '0_Start' THEN t1.stepdate
       END AS "0_Start_Date",
       CASE
         WHEN t1.step = '1_Material' THEN t1.stepdate
       END AS "1_Material_Date",
       CASE
         WHEN t1.step = '3_Build' THEN t1.stepdate
       END AS "3_Build_Date",
       t1.buildlocation
FROM   dbo.build_main_process AS t1
       INNER JOIN dbo.build_main_process AS t2
               ON t1.productcode = t2.productcode
                  AND t1.operatorname = t2.operatorname
                  AND t1.step = t2.step
                  AND t1.stepdate = t2.stepdate
                  AND t1.buildlocation = t2.buildlocation
```

[image]